# How do I catch a target="_blank" inside a WebView on Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In Titanium Appcelerator, I got a webview.
Inside the webview the page contains

I want to intercept these in Titanium.
Already tried the "load" and "click" event handlers but seems they do not work on these cases.

Any advice on how to catch and handle internal new window links on Titanium WebViews?

Comment: the page contains what?

Comment: The page has a webview that loads a remote web page that has some links.
I want to intercept the link and force it to open in the same window (or do something else i.e. if it links to a file I would like it to download it).